# C++ - Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around variable 'sourceCount' was corrupted

Tags: c++

I found similar SO question but different from mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751964/run-time-check-failure-2-stack-around-the-variable-indices-was-corrupted).

My function looks like this:

```
BOOL ShallowCopy(const LPVOID psource, LPVOID pdest) {
    LPBYTE ps = reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(psource);
    LPBYTE pd = reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(pdest);
    ULONG sourceCount = 0, destCount = 0;

    std::copy(ps, ps + 8, checked_array_iterator<LPBYTE>(((LPBYTE)((LPVOID)&sourceCount)), 8)); // Get psource byte count
    std::copy(pd, pd + 8, checked_array_iterator<LPBYTE>(((LPBYTE)((LPVOID)&destCount)), 8));       //  Get pdest byte count

    if (sourceCount != destCount) {
        SetLastError(ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER);
        return FALSE;
    }

    std::copy(ps, ps + sourceCount, checked_array_iterator<unsigned char *>(pd, destCount));
    return TRUE;
}
```

When I call the function like this:

```
if (!ShallowCopy(pcsbi, &csbi)) {
    cerr << _T("FATAL: Shallow copy failed.") << endl;
}
```

System throws runtime exception, saying "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around variable 'sourceCount' was corrupted."

But, if I cast the sourceCount and destCount into a variable, I won't get this error:

```
    BOOL ShallowCopy(const LPVOID psource, LPVOID pdest) {
    LPBYTE ps = reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(psource);
    LPBYTE pd = reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(pdest);
    LPBYTE pbCount = new BYTE[8];
    ULONG sourceCount = 0, destCount = 0;

    std::copy(ps, ps + 8, checked_array_iterator<LPBYTE>(pbCount, 8));  // Get psource byte count
    sourceCount = *((PULONG)pbCount);
    std::copy(pd, pd + 8, checked_array_iterator<LPBYTE>(pbCount, 8));      //  Get pdest byte count
    destCount = *((PULONG)pbCount);

    delete[] pbCount;

    if (sourceCount != destCount) {
        SetLastError(ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER);
        return FALSE;
    }

    std::copy(ps, ps + sourceCount, checked_array_iterator<unsigned char *>(pd, destCount));
    return TRUE;
}
```

When I look at this 2 function, I don't see much difference, except the later store the value into variable, then cast to target. So, what actually cause the run-time error?

Comment: what is `csbi` and `pcsbi` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ULONG` is defined as `unsigned long` then it's just 32 bit (4 bytes, not 8 as in your code).

You have that error because you're overwriting memory after stack allocated variable `destCount` (or `sourceCount`, where and in which order they are is just an implementation detail). In your second example it works because you're allocating enough memory (`pbCount` is 8 bytes) and this `sourceCount = *((PULONG)pbCount);` will copy just 4 of them.

I'd suggest to use `sizeof` instead of hard coded data type size:

```
std::copy(ps, ps + sizeof(ULONG)...
```

Please note that you may even simply write:

```
sourceCount = *reinterpret_cast<PULONG>(ps);
destCount = *reinterpret_cast<PULONG>(pd);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you explanation are just the thing I'm looking for.